# Loading JavaScript source in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

I tried

```html
<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation" class="resp-iframe" src="https://www.bing.com/" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

How do I insert/inject JavaScript code into this iframe?

Comment: You *can't* access inside a cross origin iframe. Not possible to insert any js

Comment: Any other way? To do it or is there any js snippet to block popup windows or any type of adds

Comment: No, only if you have the permission of the owner of the domain in the iframe, you can ask them to add your domain to their cross-origin policies so you can do this.

Comment: actully its me myself im doing it with scripts in my xampp